# Problems when plotting integrated singular functions in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib, scientific-computing

I want to plot the integral of an integral of (singular) function in matplotlib, but my code doesn't work. Mathematically I want this:

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def g(x):
    if (np.abs(x)<1e-10):
        res = x
    else:
        res = x*(np.sin(1.0/x))
    return res

X = np.arange(-0.5,0.5,0.001)

plot(X,g(X)) ## Doesn't work

def f(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(g,0,val)
        res[i]=y
    return res

plot(X,f(X)) ## Works

def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(f,0,val)
        res[i]=y
    return res

plt.plot(X,F(X)) ## Doesn't work
```

(Code is an adapted version of https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21871/9417)

So I can't plot the original function g, because it says:

```
      5 
      6 def g(x):
----> 7     if (np.abs(x)<1e-10):
      8         res = x
      9     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And also I cannot plot the integrated integral-function as it says:

```
     17 def f(x):
     18     res = np.zeros_like(x)
---> 19     for i,val in enumerate(x):
     20         y,err = integrate.quad(g,0,val)
     21         res[i]=y

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

However plotting the first integral f works. How can I fix this? Is there a better method of plotting this with python without running into such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

- When you run `g(X)`, the parameter is an array, while in the inside of the function you treat `X` as a value. `g(x)` is not applied to every element of `X`, it is applied to the whole array `X`. This explains why `The truth value of an array...` error, because `x` is in fact the whole array `X`. You can solve it in 2 different ways:

  1. Mapping the function `g` to every value of `X`

     ```
     >>> y = map(X, g)  # y = np.asarray(map(X, g)) if you want a numpy array back
     >>> plot(X, y)
     ```

  `y = map(X, g)` can also be written using list comprehension as `y = [g(x) for x in X]`.

  2. Vectorize the function `g(x)` to be applied to the whole array

     ```
     def g(X):
         r = X.copy() # create a copy of x
         mask = np.abs(r) < 1e-10   # create a mask with invalid values
         r[mask] *= np.sin(1.0 / r[mask])  # replace those values
         return r
     ```

  However, if you choose option 2, the function `f(x)` will fail, as it is calling `g(x)` with a single value, once for every value of `X`.
- Your function `f(x)` is made to work with arrays instead, as you loop over every element of `X` and apply `g(x)` to each of them. If you still want to apply `g(x)` to every element of `X` use `option 1`.
- Your function `F(x)` also works with whole arrays, as you loop through its elements. However, for every element you call `f(x)`, which only admits lists/arrays as input (and you are giving a single number). I think `F(x)` is redundant as it does exactly the same as `f(x)`.

With your definition, you can rewrite equations as follows:

```
def g(x):
    return x if np.abs(x) < 1e-10 else x * np.sin(1.0/x)

def f(x):
    return integrate.quad(g, 0, x)[0]

def F(x):
    return integrate.quad(f, 0, x)[0]
```

And then obtain the result by mapping the function for every x.

```
X = np.arange(0,0.5,0.01)
yg = map(g, X)
yf = map(f, X)
yF = map(F, X)
```

Plot results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.arange(-0.5, 0.5, 0.01)
yf = map(f, X)
plt.plot(X, yf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

A Quicker version that allows limiting the number of points within the integral:

```
def g(x):
    return x if np.abs(x) < 1e-10 else x * np.sin(1.0/x)

def f(x, limit=50):
    return integrate.quad(g, 0, x, limit=limit)[0]

def F(x, limit=50):
    return integrate.quad(f, 0, x, args=limit, limit=limit)[0]
```

Then run:

```
X = np.arange(-0.5, 0.5, 0.01)
FY = [F(x, limit=10) for x in X]
plt.plot(X, FY)
```

Larger values of `limit` will result in better representation of the image, at the expenses of much larger running times.

[image]

Comment: @Thanks, but F is not redundant, it is mathematically another function than f which is another function than g and F is what I want to plot at the end

Comment: @student without a proper definition of what `F` is suppose to do is hard to say how to fix it. But in your examples, `f(X)` calls `g(x)` for every value of `x`, and `F(X)` calls `f(x)` for every value. There is something wrong with your definition of either `F(X)` or `f(x)`.

Comment: Mathematically it should be $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt$ and $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$.

Comment: Oh, mathjax doesn't seem to be active on this site, I hope you understand my latex code.

Comment: See my edit (I just used latex and inserted an image to make clear what I want mathematically).

Comment: About your question: I think you mean "domain" and not "range". Note that the integral is also defined if the upper limit is lower than the lower limit. In my example $x < 0$. In this case the integral is just defined as minus the integral with swapped limits. So it makes indeed sense to use [0.5,0.5] as domain for the plot and I also want this for my purpose.

Comment: @student Yep I was refering to domain. Plots show ok to me. Find edited plot.

Comment: @Ok, I realized that it works with python 2.7 but not with python3. I was able to reproduce the plot for f, but for F it is calculating since 30 min.  Maybe the code is not very efficient.

Comment: @student nope the code is not very efficient. Partially due to the very dense discretization that both your `range` and the `integral.quad` do. It can be speed up by using a different approach (e.g. avoid using `quad` recursively as it is too expensive or play with the parameters of `quad`, such as `limit=10` to limit the number of evaluations), but that is a completely different question. (see edit)